# How to read the last but one entry of the particular userid from file in JAVA

Tags: java

Hi Im using eclipse in Windows 10 OS.
Every time the user logins.I'm checking that particular user id last but one entry in the file and checking if the user is logged out or not.The file entries looks like[image: The picture of how the file structure looks like]
Here first parameter is timestamp,second is INFO,third is login or logout status and the numbers 10,1 and 3 are the userid 
Now i need to check the last but one entry of that particular userid and change the value based on login or logged out.
I'm passing the userid to the function has an arguement so the JAVA code needs to check that particular userid's (which is passed as parameter) last but one entry

i have written the java code like this

```
public static boolean User(String userid) {

        try {
            String acc = userid;
            File file = new File("C:\\Temp\\log\\bank.log");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(file);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                String[] substrings = data.split("[:]");
                if (substrings[5].contains(acc) && substrings[4].contains("Login Successful for user")) {
                    a = true;
                } else {
                    a = false;
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here I'm passing userid in User() function.What changes should be made so that i will be getting the information of the last but one entry of that particular userid in java.Could anyone please help me with the changes that should be made.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static boolean isLogin(String userId) {
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\Temp\\log\\bank.log");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(file);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                String[] substrings = data.split("[:]");
                if (substrings[5].contentEquals(" " + userId) && substrings[4].contentEquals(" Login Successful for user")) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: what if the file structure is like this   10:30:03:INFO:Login Successful for user : 1
10:30:25:INFO:Login Successful for user : 1 
 11:30:03:INFO:Logout Successful for user : 1
 11:30:03:INFO:Login Successful for user : 1
  12:30:03:INFO:Login Successful for user : 2
 12:30:03:INFO:Login Successful for user : 2
 12:30:03:INFO:Login Successful for user : 1    and i need to check the last but one entry information of the userid (note it is last but one entry and not the previous or the latest entry in the file of that particular user) could you please suggest any method for this scenario.